# $C^{\infty}$ 1-form on a Riemann surface is unique.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $\mathcal{A}$ be a complex atlas on $X$. Suppose that  $C^{\infty}$ 1-forms are given for each chart of $\mathcal{A}$, which transform to each other on their common domains. Then there exists a unique $C^{\infty}$ 1-form on $X$ extending these   $C^{\infty}$ 1-forms on each of the charts of $\mathcal{A}$.

This is Lemma 1.13 from Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces by R.Miranda.

> Definition: Let $X$ be a Riemann surface. A $C^{\infty}$ 1-form on $X$ is a collection of $C^{\infty}$ 1-forms $\{\omega_\phi\}$, one for each chart $\phi:U\to V$in the variable of the target $V$, such that if two charts $\phi_i:U_i\to V_i$(for $i=1,2$) have overlapping domains, then the associated $C^{\infty}$ 1-form $\{\omega_{\phi_1}\}$ transforms to $\{\omega_{\phi_2}\}$ under the change of coordinate mapping $T=\phi_1\circ \phi_2^{-1} .$

So, if we let $\{\rho_\phi\}$ be another $C^{\infty}$ 1-form collection defined similarly.  Then I am thinking to show that both collections are the same we need to show that $C^{\infty}$ 1-form $\{\omega_{\phi_1}\}$ transforms to $\{\rho_{\phi_2}\}$  and $C^{\infty}$ 1-form $\{\rho_{\phi_1}\}$ transforms to $\{\omega_{\phi_2}\}$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If the local $ 1 $-forms $ \omega_{i} $ defined respectively on the charts $ U_{i} $ transform correctly, then the global $ 1 $-form $ \omega $ that you seek is obtained simply by ‘gluing’ the $ \omega_{i} $’s together. In other words, $ \omega|_{U_{i}} = \omega_{i} $. This is a verification of Sheaf Axiom $ 2 $ for the presheaf of differential $ 1 $-forms on a Riemann surface (see the Wikipedia article on [Sheaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics))).

Comment: Partition of Unity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity

Comment: Well if you give a form for each chart for both $\{\rho_\phi\}$ and $\{\omega_\phi\}$, and you want the forms to be exactly the same, then you just want them to be exactly the same form on each chart, i.e. $\rho_\phi=\omega_\phi$ for all $\phi$... No need to transform...